# How many police/SWAT team/soldiers/nazis/cowboys are there in the final chase scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blues-brothers

I was watching the Blues Brothers recently and I was wondering how many people were there chasing Elwood and Jake in the final chase scene, including the army, police and swat teams, soldiers and vigilantes, and all the other groups.

I would think at least 300.

Comment: To quote young John Connor from T2: "Uh... all of 'em, I think."

Comment: You forgot: rustlers, cut throats, murderers, bounty hunters, desperados, mugs, pugs, thugs, nitwits, halfwits, dimwits, vipers, snipers, con men, Indian agents, Mexican bandits, muggers, buggerers, bushwhackers, hornswogglers, horse thieves, bull dykes, train robbers, bank robbers, ass-kickers, shit-kickers. And especially Methodists.

Comment: ...and country musicians.

Comment: @DVK, I thought that was in Blazing Saddles??? At the time, the number of automobiles wrecked in the movie set a record that broke the one held by The French Connection.

Comment: Also: The sportos, the motorheads, geeks, sluts, bloods, wastoids, dweebies, dickheads..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to an [article in the Chicago Sun Times](http://web.archive.org/web/20050911010626/http://www.suntimes.com/special_sections/bluebros/cst-nws-bbdaley24.html), over **500** extras were used for the scene:

> Aykroyd remembers a "day of intense concentration'' while working with so many extras -- more than **500**, including **200** real soldiers. Belushi hurt his back pushing a cigarette machine and a bench in front of the fake doors, recalled his widow, Judy Belushi Pisano.

> If you came upon Daley Plaza on Labor Day weekend 1979, you might have turned and run for cover. **Two hundred** National Guardsmen, rifles in hand, raced from Army jeeps and tanks toward the Cook County Building. They were backed up by **three** Sherman tanks, **three** helicopters and **three** fire trucks. Not to mention **100** state and city police officers in 50 squad cars and on 15 horses.
>
> There was even **a SWAT team** crawling across the roof and rappelling down the Corinthian columns of the building.